# Target element within scope using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Is there a simple way to target an element within a scope and change the class name or styling.

I used to use Jquery and simply use .parent().find to target relative elements, but can't find a simple solution that should accomplish quite a simple task.

Most solutions seem to be be very complicated and I'm sure angular removes the need for lots of code.

I want to either target relative to the ng-click element or from the root of the scope and apply a new class name.

Here is very basic scenario where I need the button to change the class of H1.

```
<div>
    <h1 class="Blue">Welcome</h1>
    <ul>
       <li>
           <button ng-click="myFunction()">Change H1 to Red</button>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are toggling classes it is best to use `ng-class` and switch on some property:

**html:**

```
<div>
    <h1 ng-class="{Blue: !clicked, Red: clicked}">Welcome</h1>
    <ul>
       <li>
           <button ng-click="myFunction()">Change H1 to Red</button>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.myFunction = function() {
   $scope.clicked = true;
}
```

However, you can pass in `$event` in the function to get the raw element as well by doing this.  Although, this would not be the "angular" way to do things:

**html:**

```
<button ng-click="myFunction($event)">Change H1 to Red</button>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.myFunction = function(e) {
   console.log(e.srcElement);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - both have their use but the first example suits my needs, just what I needed